# How to deploy the project to the server?

Tags: php, laravel, server, voyager

I did a test project on Laravel voyager. I want to publish it to the server.

I try this:

git init

1. git remote add origin ***
2. git checkout master
3. git pull
4. add .env
5. add .htaccess
6. php artisan migrate --force

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class
>   'TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider' not found

How to do it?

Update:

> php artisan composer install run – Kamlesh Paul
>
> In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class
>   'TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider' not found

Comment: `php artisan composer install` run

Comment: Have you checked whether composer got executed, or have you put all `vendor` files under version control?

Answer (score 0):

typically there are few configuration steps to take with laravel projects. checkout this post for details -https://devmarketer.io/learn/setup-laravel-project-cloned-github-com/

Comment: I can just deploy a project on Laravel. My question is deployment with a voyager. php artisan is not working.